# How can i insert a ul element before another existing ul element in my website's footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website that has a documentation section powered by Atlassian Confluence. In the footer of my documentation there is some information by Atlassian as shown in the picture.

What I am trying to do is to add a sentence above it. So far I have only been able to add it underneath the existing ul. On confluence I can only override elements by inserting new code in a custom HTML block.

[My website's footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUblW.png)

This is the code I get from the footer when I inspect the footer element on my web browser.

```html
<section class="footer-body">  
    <ul id="poweredby">...</ul>  
</section>
```

and this is the code I am inserting into the custom HTML block to get my sentence on the footer. (As seen on the picture)

```html
<ul id="copyright">
  <li class="noprint"> THIS INFORMATION SHOULD BE ABOVE </li>
</ul>
```

How can I change this code so it gets inserted above the existing confluence sentence?

Comment: I like @Hitmands answer but if you wanted to create the elements dynamically, you could do this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awJLxb. Not sure if that helps. I can submit as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as documented here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

```js
function move() {
  var copyright = document.querySelector('#copyright');
  var target = document.querySelector('#poweredby');

  target.parentNode.insertBefore(copyright, target);
}

window.setTimeout(move, 3000);
```

```html
<section class="footer-body">  
    <ul id="poweredby">
      <li> hello world</li>
    </ul>  
</section>  

<ul id="copyright">
  <li class="noprint"> THIS INFORMATION SHOULD BE ABOVE </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery, on document load you can dinamically move one element into another

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#copyright').prependTo($('.footer-body'));
});
```

Comment: this will end up inserting the node as a first child of the container, but, he wants it just before `#poweredby`

Comment: On his example and picture, there are only 2 elements, so prepend is a valid choice

Comment: it isn't, that snippet shows only the relevant part of the OP, but you can't know the real case and your solution is error prone.

Comment: He'll decide. Maybe his footer is made up only of those elements and the answer will be valid. On the example given, it works. In other cases, it may not. :-)

Comment: you're definitely missing the point. A solution is supposed to cover all the cases, not just few, nor just one as yours. And you should also consider that there wasn't any mention about `jQuery` in the op.